# Type checking for input value by assigning attribute directly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following component that takes `count` as input. `count` is of type `number`.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'Test',
    template: ""
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() count: number;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.count, typeof this.count);
        // 123, string
    }
}
```

And in the parent template, I assign `count` attribute like this.

```
<Test count="123"></Test>
```

After compile and run the component, the type of `count` has become string. This is obviously wrong. And since I'm not using `[count]` to pass in input, type checker can not determine the type at coding time.

My question is: how to make this work? i.e. assigning through vanilla html attribute and get the correct type. Or how to do the type coercion when assigning this way.

Comment: Why not `[count]="123"`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree with you. But maybe some inexperience user just want to assign a one-time value to an html component without knowing the meaning of `[]`. Since angular allows it to be assigned, I assume this could be a valid use case.

Comment: I would be disinclined to spend much time worrying about people who are using Angular without actually knowing how to use Angular. This is likely to be approximately the least of their problems.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 'This is likely to be approximately the least of their problems' :)

Comment: @deezg they are not going to get far if they don't know how to bind things!

Comment: of course. i am just laughing your wording ;)